# Turn off app update notification sound

Tags: updates, notifications

Does anyone know how to turn off sounds for notification of app updates? Turning off notification sounds also turns off message tones. This is becoming really annoying as phone beeps every time an app updates!

Comment: I would expect you can turn off notifications for the Google Play app, no?

Comment: What phone do you have? I've never had a sound when an app is updated, just a notification in the tray.

Comment: Samsung galaxy S4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not so easy to notice at first that with Samsung phones, you have to note that there is also "GALAXY Apps" store.
It has its own notification settings.

Answer (score 0):

Playstore notifications do not trigger when an app is updated (at least with Android Oreo). But security / antivirus apps might do. I have ESET Endpoint security installed which scans every download and notifies on success. I changed the corresponding notification sound to be sure it is really the antivirus. So I could mute that notification, alas the app has only one notification category so if something bad happens I wouldn't hear it either...

Answer (score -1):

In playstore app, settings, notifications, you can turn off